# How to scroll the picklist on a TValueListEditor with the mousewheel?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

By default, the mousewheel will change rows on the TValueListEditor.  When I have a picklist, I would prefer for the mousewheel to scroll the displayed list instead.  I know how to override the default behavior, but how do I gain access to the object controlling the display of the dropdown list so that I can tell it to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TValueListEditor` has `InplaceEditor` and `EditList` properties that return a pointer to a `TInplaceEditList` object (the `InplaceEditor` property returns a `TInplaceEdit*` pointer, which you can type-cast to `TInplaceEditList*`). Both properties are declared as `protected`, so you will have to use an accessor to reach them, or derive from `TValueListEditor` so you can promote their visibility.

In either case, `TInplaceEditList` has a public `PickList` property that returns a pointer to a `TCustomListBox` object (it is actually a `TPopupListBox`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  I should note that both of those properties are protected, though.